# Determine fontsize, leadsize, pica measure with memoir

Tags: memoir

I've set up a `memoir` document with the following page layout (MWE):

```
\documentclass[%
    a4paper,
    10pt,
    twoside,
]{memoir}

%%% Layout the Page %%%
\setstocksize{297mm}{210mm}
\settrimmedsize{\stockheight}{\stockwidth}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{27.4mm}{*}{1}
\setlrmarginsandblock{24mm}{79mm}{*}
\setmarginnotes{9mm}{50mm}{1em}
\setheadfoot{1.25\baselineskip}{10mm}
\setheaderspaces{*}{8mm}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout[fixed]

\begin{document}
MWE
\end{document}
```

The log gives me this heights and widths:

```
******************************************************
Stock height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Top and edge trims: 0pt and 0pt
Page height and width: 845.04684pt by 597.50787pt
Text height and width: 689.1258pt by 304pt
Spine and edge margins: 68.2866pt and 224.77676pt
Upper and lower margins: 77.96053pt and 77.96053pt
Headheight and headsep: 15pt and 22.76219pt
Footskip: 28.45274pt
Columnsep and columnseprule: 10pt and 0pt
Marginparsep and marginparwidth: 25.60747pt and 142.26378pt
Sidecapsep and sidecapwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidebarhsep and sidebarwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidebarvsep and sidebartopsep: 12pt and 0pt
Sidebarheight: 596.39996pt
Sidefoothsep and sidefootwidth: 7pt and 117pt
Sidefootvsep and sidefootheight: 12pt and 596.39996pt
******************************************************
```

I would like to determine the font and lead size and the measure, as e.g. given in the `memoir` handbook chapter 'terminology'. So this would be 10/12 for 10pt font and 12pt lead size, I guess? Actually, how do I determine the lead size?

Eventually, how do I determine the measure, i.e. length of a text line? Is this 304pt (the text width given in the length) over 12 (points/pica), thus 304/12 = 25.333pc?

Comment: The text width is 304pt; if you want to express it as 25.333pc, there is no problem, but it's like saying that one foot is 12 inches or 1cm is 10mm. The baseline skip is usually 12pt, when the font size is 10pt; `memoir` uses this default.

Comment: Alright, I was just thinking that the measure is always given in picas, so it should be converted. But yes, you are right, saying it is 304pt is indeed clearer.

Comment: The leading is set in the appropriate `.clo` file that memoir loads. But there's no simple way to retrieve the values directly without looking at the code, or using `\show\normalsize` which will show the definition of `\normalsize` (which includes the values passed to `\@setfontsize`, the fontsize and leading).  For an explanation of how this works see [font size selection how multiple of \normalsize](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/67134).